# Быть или не быть AtomicInteger-у?

Tags: асинхронность, java

через каждую секунду в поле int происходит запись (записывает всегда один поток)
чтение значения происходит в любое время несколькими потоками.
Вроде как нужно, т.к. запись происходит, но сомневаюсь

Comment: А в чём сомневаетесь? `AtomicInteger` или `synchronized`? Берите любое, раз в секунду — не проблема.

(Если чаще, тогда лучше замерить время и сравнить._

Comment: сомневаюсь нужно ли вообще использовать, хотел просто int, но забыл что операция запись неатомарна

Comment: @shkiper: синхронизацию в каком-то виде использовать необходимо: разные потоки имеют право иметь разный вид на память. Не существует понятия «реальное содержимое памяти», у каждого потока своё представление.

Answer (score 4):

В случае, если запись и чтение этого поля будут атомарными операциями, то будет достаточно объявить его как `volatile` ([JLS 17.4.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html)).

P.S. Кстати, если заглянуть во внутренности `AtomicInteger`, то можно увидеть, что метод `set` реализован следующим нехитрым образом (поскольку эта операция атомарна):

```
public final void set(int newValue) {
    value = newValue;
}
```

А `value` объявлен как:

```
private volatile int value;
```

А вот уже всяческие pre/post-increment/decrement и прочие неатомарные операции в этом классе (`getAndDecrement()`, `getAndAdd()` и т.д.) — те да, реализованы хитрее, с синхронизацией и/или `Unsafe`, в зависимости от реализации.

Comment: я так понимаю volatile - отключение буферизации, запись же не атомарная для простых типов

Comment: Непосредственно присваивание, то есть `a = 10` — атомарно (и вообще, оно атомарно для всех примитивных типов, за исключением `long` и `double`, но и для них в JLS гарантируется атомарность, в случае, если указан модификатор `volatile`). Не атомарны, например, операции инкремента и декремента.

Указание же `volatile` в вашем случае инициирует `happens-before order` (по ссылке выше), который гарантирует, что:
> A write to a volatile field happens-before every subsequent read of that field.

Comment: @falstaf: Простого `volatile` может быть [недостаточно](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe.aspx) для ТС'а.

+1 за правильную и полезную ссылку на стандарт.

Comment: @VladD, да, в общем случае `volatile` может быть и недостаточно, потому я и уточнил, что это "в случае, если запись и чтение этого поля будут атомарными операциями".